# Error when using the Nodejs Sharp module. Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1: 0)

Tags: node.js, webpack, aws-lambda, sharp

When running webpack I have received this error
"WARNING in ./node_modules/sharp/build/Release/sharp.node 1: 0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1: 0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
@ ./node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js 11: 2-40
@ ./node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js "

Sharp was installed with the yarn add.
My operating system is ubuntu 18.04 x86_64.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 8):

If you use webpack, use `node-loader`

Install it: `npm i -D node-loader`

In `webpack.config.js`:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    { test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader" },  
    { test: /\.node$/, use: "node-loader"}
  ]
}
```